# Session Automatic timeout even refreshing page in short interval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have totally no idea why is this happening. 
I have set Timeout=20 in config
The session will timeout at around 8 minutes.
I have tried to refresh the page 1 or 2 times every minute.
But the session still timeout automatically and forcing the user to be redirected to Login page.

Have you guys ever encounter this problem?

I am hosting a ASP.NET WebForm at a shared web hosting.
Database is MySQL

Comment: what is the code?

Comment: @Sherlock Without the code, it is impossible to identify the problem right? Ya, I know that. But it is a big project, lots of files. I am unable to show it all here. Guess, I will have to go back and check all those lines one by one.... aw....

Comment: what middleware did you use? owin? asp? please at least be specific. Can't connect the dots

Comment: @Sherlock I am hosting a ASP.NET WebForm at a shared web hosting.
Database is MySQL.

Comment: @Sherlock hey, dude, I am going to try an auto-refresh by calling a page within an iframe by using javascript to refresh the session automatically every 30 seconds to keep the session stay alive. I'm going to test it out tonight and report it back here later. Thanks for your time. I'll see you around.

Comment: Did you set `<sessionState mode="InProc" />` in the web.config?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez No I did not.

Comment: @Sherlock oh man... even I use a javascript to reload a page to refresh the session every 30 seconds in an IFRAME, the system still redirect the user to login page if the user click any link within an uncertain amount of time!!!! I didn't even click anything!!! well.... this is the first time I encounter something like this. It would be interesting if I found the cause of problem. I'll keep you updated once I found it.

Comment: Is [SlidingExpiration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx) turned on?

Comment: @Sherlock well, the problem gone now. What I have done is just restart the website at the web hosting control panel. I just don't know why..... nothing obvious have changed within the code.

Comment: @JohnWu well, the problem gone now. What I have done is just restart the website at the web hosting control panel. I just don't know why..... nothing obvious have changed within the code.

Comment: @Sherlock Problem identified. The memory consumption has reached the limit which allocated for the website in the shared web hosting plan. The application pool recycled automatically and forcing the website to restart.

Comment: @JohnWu Problem identified. The memory consumption has reached the limit which allocated for the website in the shared web hosting plan. The application pool recycled automatically and forcing the website to restart.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Problem identified. The memory consumption has reached the limit which allocated for the website in the shared web hosting plan. The application pool recycled automatically and forcing the website to restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem identified. The memory consumption has reached the limit which allocated for the website in the shared web hosting plan. The application pool recycled automatically and forcing the website to restart.